# Multiple character delimiter in hadoop raw logs

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I have the following data coming in the raw logs:

```
    America^|#|^Northern America^|#|^United States^|#|^Texas^|#|^Houston TX
```

Here the delimiter is ^|#|^

However on passing the delimiter to create external table, only the first character ^ is being considered as the delimiter.

Code used was :

```
    create external table xyz 
    (
    col_name1 string,
    col_name2 string,
    col_name3 string,
    col_name4 string,
    col_name5 string,
    )

    row format delimited 
    fields terminated by '^!#!^'
    lines terminated by '\n'

    location '/data/raw/table;
```

Was expecting a table like this:

```
col_name1  col_name2         col_name3      col_name4  col_name5
America    Northern America  United States  Texas      Houston TX
```

Instead the output I got was:

```
col_name1   col_name2   col_name3           col_name4   col_name5
America     |#|         Northern America    |#|         United States
```

Does anyone know how to pass multiple characters as delimiter?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Better to replace this delimiter by some single character delimiter. Or if really multi character delimiter is required then use Unicode characters.